# If $L = \lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)$ prove that $\lim_{t\to \infty}(1/t)\int_0^tf(x)dx = L$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and suppose $L = \lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)$ exists. Prove that $\lim_{t\to \infty}(1/t)\int_0^tf(x)dx = L$

My solution:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and choose $\delta = {2\over 3}\epsilon$. Since $L = \lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)$, we have that there exists a $t_1$ such that $\forall t\geq t_1$ we have $|f(t) - L| < \delta$. Since $t_1$ is fixed for any given $\delta$, $\int_0^{t_1}|f(x) - L|dx$ is bounded by some $M \in \mathbb{R}$. Now choose $t_2$ such that $\forall t \geq t_2$ we have ${M \over t} < {\delta \over 2}$. Let $t_0 = \max(t_1,t_2)$. Then

\begin{align}
   |{1\over t}\int_0^tf(x)dx - L | & = & \mid{1\over t}\int_0^tf(x)dx - L{1\over t}\int_0^tdx \mid \\
   & = & \mid{1\over t}\int_0^t(f(x) - L )dx  \mid\\
&\leq &{1\over \mid t \mid}\int_0^t \mid f(x) - L \mid dx\\
&\leq & {1\over \mid t \mid}\int_0^{t_0} \mid f(x) - L \mid dx + {M\over \mid t \mid}\int_{t_0}^{t} \mid f(x) - L \mid dx\\
&<& {M\over \mid t \mid } + {\delta\mid t - t_0 \mid \over\mid t \mid }.
\end{align} Since $t\in [0, \infty),$ we have ${\mid t - t_0 \mid \over \mid t \mid }\delta \leq \delta$. Then ${M\over \mid t \mid} + {\mid t - t_0 \mid \over \mid t \mid }\delta < {\delta \over 2} + \delta = {3\over 2} \delta = \epsilon.$ Therefore $\lim_{t\to \infty}(1/t)\int_0^tf(x)dx = L$.

Please tell me if my solution is correct, and if not please point out any mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving The Average Value of a Function with Infinite Length](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435820/proving-the-average-value-of-a-function-with-infinite-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the solution is correct. There's a way to make it cleaner  **and** get more general result, by using $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. Like this:
$$
\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f = \limsup_{t\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{t}\int_0^T f +\frac{t-T}{t}\frac{1}{t-T}\int_T^t f\right) = \limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t-T}\int_T^t f  
$$
Here $\frac{1}{t-T}\int_T^t f  \le \sup_{[T,\infty)} f$, so we end up with 
$$
\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f \le \sup_{[T,\infty)} f
$$
Since this is true for every $T$, it follows that 
$$
\limsup_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f \le \limsup_{t\to\infty} f(t) \tag1
$$
Note that the existence of $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$ is not used above; the inequality (1) is rather general.  Applying (1) to $-f$, we get
$$
\liminf_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f \ge \liminf_{t\to\infty} f(t) \tag2
$$
If $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$ happens to exist, the desired conclusion follows from (1) and (2).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to prove this using L'Hopitals rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

As $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=L$, then it can be proven that $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_{0}^t f(x)=\infty$

And as $\lim_{t\to \infty}t=\infty$, we have an indetermination $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, therefore we can apply L'Hopitals rule on the limit and the fundamental theorem of calculus to obtain

$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^t f(x)}{t}=\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{1}=L$