# Limit of average of real function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, functions

I need some hints regarding this exercice.

if $f : [0, \infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function s.t $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = a$, prove :

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(t)dt = a.
\end{align}

If I try to integrate the lim inside of the integral by the monotone convergence theorem, I end up with a pathological case $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: I think you need to assume $f$ is integrable over bounded sets. You should be able to use the ideas in the second answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435820/proving-the-average-value-of-a-function-with-infinite-length) for a proof.

Comment: The usual epsilon-delta approach (or rather, epsilon-x_0) works perfectly here: let epsilon be positive, then there exists some x_0 such that...

Answer (score 0):

If you have that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^xf(t)dt=\infty$$
the simplest way is to use L'Hopital rule
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_0^xf(t)dt}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=a.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Is there any other proof using measure theory techniques ? I haven't seen l'Hopital rule in the book I'm reading and I'm guessing there is a measure theoric proof to it.